# Image does not seem to be uploaded to Firebase storage although no error is thrown

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-storage

I am building a social media app. In the app I have a form that allows users to upload an image to firebase storage.

the images appear in folders in firebase storage (i.e. attached below) but somehow when I click on the image , it redirects me to a blank page and a popup appears

[image]

[image]

After saving the image, I tried to open it on my computer but it says "It appears that we don't support this file format."
Similarly, when I try to include the firebase link to my img in my react app using Img tag, it doesn't appear in the app but shows up as a icon.

Here's my code snippet for setting image as state using react hooks:

```
const handleFileChange = (e) => {
    setImage(null);
    let selected = e.target.files[0];
    console.log(selected);

    if (!selected) {
      setImgError("Please select a file.");
      return;
    }

    if (!selected.type.includes("image")) {
      setImgError("Selected file must be an image.");
      return;
    }
    if (!selected.size > 100000) {
      setImgError("Image file size must be less than 100kb.");
      return;
    }

    setImgError(null);
    setImage(selected);
  };
```

Here's my code snippet for the uploading of image to firebase storage (I am using firebase v9):

```
const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    let time = new Date().valueOf();
    const file = `images/${user.uid}/${time}/${image.name}`;
    const storageRef = ref(storage, file);
    await uploadBytes(storageRef, file).then((snapshot) => {
      getDownloadURL(snapshot.ref).then((url) =>
        addDoc(collection(db, "posts"), {
          uid: user.uid,
          caption: caption,
          post: post,
          displayName: user.displayName,
          imgURL: url,
          comments: [],
          likes: [],
        })
      );
    });
    setCaption("");
    setPost("");
    history.push("/home");
  };
```

EDIT: I tried following the documentation for uploading files [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/upload-files#web-version-9_1) and made these changes as follows:

```
const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    let time = new Date().valueOf();
    const storage = getStorage();
    const file = `${image.name}`;
    const storageRef = ref(storage, `images/${user.uid}/${time}/${image.name}`);

    uploadBytes(storageRef, file).then((snapshot) => {
      console.log("Uploaded a blob or file!");
    });
```

I'm not too sure what is expected as the 2nd argument (& the format of it) in `storageRef`; I'm assuming its the location of where I want the file to be stored.
Would appreciate any help/insights on this. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Your `file` variable is wrong in this snippet:

```
const file = `images/${user.uid}/${time}/${image.name}`;
const storageRef = ref(storage, file);
await uploadBytes(storageRef, file).then((snapshot) => {
```

The second argument to [`uploadBytes`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/storage.md#uploadbytes) expects:

> Blob | Uint8Array | ArrayBuffer   The data to upload.

But you are passing it a string with the path that you want the file to have on the server, which is not one of the expected types.

As the sample in the documentation on [uploading files](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/upload-files#upload_from_a_blob_or_file) says:

```
import { getStorage, ref, uploadBytes } from "firebase/storage";

const storage = getStorage();
const storageRef = ref(storage, 'some-child');

// 'file' comes from the Blob or File API
uploadBytes(storageRef, file).then((snapshot) => {
  console.log('Uploaded a blob or file!');
});
```

So I expect that you'll want to pass in `e.target.files[0]` or something like that.

Comment: Hi Frank, thank you so much for your reply. I've just tried the above, but it seems like I am still facing the same issue - I'm unable to open the files in firebase storage although they appear there. I'm guessing I'm still passing something incorrect as an argument in `storageRef`. May I clarify what  the argument 'some-child' should be?  I've edited the post & the code snippet I've used is under the "EDIT" section.  Thank you.

Comment: That code in the edit still does the same type of thing, with ``const file = `${image.name}` ``. The `file` you pass in `uploadBytes(storageRef, file)` needs to be a reference to the file that the user selected in the browser, not a string you construct.

Comment: Thanks a lot Frank! I managed to make it work after making the changes you suggested & changing my firebase settings :)

Comment: Good to hear @Kalamazoo. Don't forget to click the upvote/accept buttons on the left of my answer.